# How to INNER JOIN 3 tables using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Can someone Tell me how to join 3 table with php?
Example

```
SELECT FROM table1, table2,table on INNERJOIN -------------------
```

let I have 3 table.(question table ,answer table and category table)
Here is example form my webpage.

```
Time remaining 30 minutes(I will get "30 minutes" form Category table)
1. Question (from question table)
2. answer (from answer table)
```

I don't know how to join 3 table.

Comment: How are you doing this?  With an SQL statement hard coded in?, with a framework like ActiveRecord? or something else?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

it should be like that,

```
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.id');
$this->db->join('table3', 'table1.id = table3.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

as per  CodeIgniters active record framework

Answer (score 4):

I believe that using CodeIgniters active record framework that you would just use two join statements one after the other.
eg:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table1', 'table1.id = table2.id');
$this->db->join('table1', 'table1.id = table3.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Give that a try and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank Klee,Can you tell me if not codeigniter?How to join three table with Sql command ? Sorry for my bad english usage.Please patient me.

Answer (score 2):

I think in CodeIgniter the best to use ActiveRecord as wrote above.
One more thing: you can use method chaining in AR:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('table1')->join('table2','table1.id=table2.id')->...
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a function to get an array with the values ​​for the fields and to join. This goes in the model:

```
  public function GetDataWhereExtenseJoin($table,$fields,$data) {
    //pega os campos passados para o select
    foreach($fields as $coll => $value){
        $this->db->select($value);
    }
    //pega a tabela
    $this->db->from($table);
    //pega os campos do join
    foreach($data as $coll => $value){
        $this->db->join($coll, $value);
    }
    //obtem os valores
    $query = $this->db->get();
    //retorna o resultado
    return $query->result();

}
```

This goes in the controller:

```
$data_field = array(
        'NameProduct' => 'product.IdProduct',
        'IdProduct' => 'product.NameProduct',
        'NameCategory' => 'category.NameCategory',
        'IdCategory' => 'category.IdCategory'
        );
    $data_join = array
                    ( 'product' => 'product_category.IdProduct = product.IdProduct',
                      'category' => 'product_category.IdCategory = category.IdCategory',
                      'product' => 'product_category.IdProduct = product.IdProduct'
                    );
    $product_category = $this->mmain->GetDataWhereExtenseJoin('product_category', $data_field, $data_join);
```

result:

```
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($product_category);
    die;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.id','JOIN Type');
$this->db->join('table3', 'table1.id = table3.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

> this will give you result from table1,table2,table3 and you can use any type of join in the third variable of $this->db->join() function such as inner,left, right etc.

Answer (score 1):

For executing pure SQL statements (I Don't Know About the FRAMEWORK- CodeIGNITER!!!)
you can use SUB QUERY!
The Syntax Would be as follows

SELECT t1.id
FROM example t1 INNER JOIN 
(select id from (example2 `t1` join example3 `t2` on `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`)) as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;

Hope you Get My Point!

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('table1');
$this->db->join('table2', 'table1.id = table2.id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('table3', 'table1.id = table3.id', 'inner');
$this->db->where("table1", $id );
$query = $this->db->get();
```

---

Where you can specify which id should be viewed or select in specific table. You can also select which join portion either left, right, outer, inner, left outer, and right outer on the third parameter of join method.

Answer (score 1):

you can modiv your coding like this

```
 $this->db->select('a.nik,b.nama,a.inv,c.cekin,c.cekout,a.tunai,a.nontunai,a.id');
 $this->db->select('DATEDIFF (c.cekout, c.cekin) as lama');
 $this->db->select('(DATEDIFF (c.cekout, c.cekin)*c.total) as tagihan');
 $this->db->from('bayar as a');
 $this->db->join('pelanggan as b', 'a.nik = b.nik');
 $this->db->join('pesankamar_h as c', 'a.inv = c.id');
 $this->db->where('a.user_id',$id);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->result();
```

i hope can be resolve your SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
function fetch_comments($ticket_id){
    $this->db->select('tbl_tickets_replies.comments, 
           tbl_users.username,tbl_roles.role_name');
    $this->db->where('tbl_tickets_replies.ticket_id',$ticket_id);
    $this->db->join('tbl_users','tbl_users.id = tbl_tickets_replies.user_id');
    $this->db->join('tbl_roles','tbl_roles.role_id=tbl_tickets_replies.role_id');
    return $this->db->get('tbl_tickets_replies');
}
```