# Codeigniter active record how to join five tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following database schema[image]

I am using codeigniter.I need to get data from all the tables ,by giving id of question_banks  table.So how should I write the join clause for this using active record class of codeigniter.I know it is possible to join two tables.But how can I join all these tables.

Comment: Uploaded only one image ..but it is shown twice here ???????????????????/

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440371/how-to-inner-join-3-tables-using-codeigniter

Comment: dump your table structure

Answer (score 3):

It is not the best one but I think it will help

```
$this->db->select('questions.question, question_categories.name, options.value, question_banks.name');    
$this->db->from('questions');
$this->db->join('question_categories', 'questions.question_category_id = question_categories.id');
$this->db->join('options','options.option_id=questions.id');
$this->db->join('question_bank_questions', 'questions.id = question_bank_questions.question_id');
$this->db->join('question_banks', 'question_bank_questions.question_bank_id = question_bank.id');
```